# EnterCriticalSection identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, chromium-embedded

Ok, I'm compiling a project that is using the [Chromium Embedded Framework 3](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/).  I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2013 RC.  Officially, VS2013 RC is not supported by CEF3.  However, I require VS2013 due to C++11 features that are only available in VS2013.

I downloaded the CEF3 64 bit binaries, and compiled their sample application using VS2013.  It worked beautifully (although I had to add the `<algorithm>` header file to some of the cef3 header files).

Now, when I include some of the CEF3 files into my project, I'm getting a bunch of compile errors.  I'm using SCons to compile my project.  It looks almost like some variables and defines are not getting set/called when the CEF3 header file(s) include the `<windows.h>` header file...

The errors are:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fobuild\gui\GUI.obj /c src\gui\GUI.cpp /TP /w /wd4350 /EHsc /MD /DDEBUG /DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.0.1\" /DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/issues\" /DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
cl /Fobuild\gui\HtmlGuiComponent.obj /c src\gui\HtmlGuiComponent.cpp /TP /w /wd4350 /EHsc /MD /DDEBUG /DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.0.1\" /DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/issues\" /DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
GUI.cpp
HtmlGuiComponent.cpp
cl /Fobuild\models\ModelManager.obj /c src\models\ModelManager.cpp /TP /w /wd4350 /EHsc /MD /DDEBUG /DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.0.1\" /DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/issues\" /DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
ModelManager.cpp
cl /Fobuild\glw\Animation.obj /c src\glw\Animation.cpp /TP /w /wd4350 /EHsc /MD /DDEBUG /DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.0.1\" /DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/jarrettchisholm/glr/issues\" /DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
Animation.cpp
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(55) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'instance'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(55) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(70) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'parent_window'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(70) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(71) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'menu'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(71) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(86) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'window'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(86) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types.h(83) : error C2371: 'char16' : redefinition; different basic types
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_string_types.h(51) : see declaration of 'char16'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(65) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_sec'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(65) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(52) : error C2065: 'm_sec' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(52) : error C2065: 'CRITICAL_SECTION' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(52) : error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(53) : error C2065: 'm_sec' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(53) : error C3861: 'InitializeCriticalSection': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(56) : error C2065: 'm_sec' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(56) : error C3861: 'DeleteCriticalSection': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(59) : error C2065: 'm_sec' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(59) : error C3861: 'EnterCriticalSection': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(62) : error C2065: 'm_sec' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(62) : error C3861: 'LeaveCriticalSection': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(84) : error C2039: 'instance' : is not a member of '_cef_main_args_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(54) : see declaration of '_cef_main_args_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(54) : see declaration of '_cef_main_args_t'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(96) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HINSTANCE'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(96) : error C2535: 'CefMainArgs::CefMainArgs(void)' : member function already defined or declared
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(93) : see declaration of 'CefMainArgs::CefMainArgs'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(97) : error C2065: 'instance' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(97) : error C2065: 'hInstance' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(120) : error C2039: 'parent_window' : is not a member of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(121) : error C2039: 'menu' : is not a member of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(122) : error C2039: 'window' : is not a member of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
        C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_types_win.h(61) : see declaration of '_cef_window_info_t'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(139) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HWND'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(149) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HWND'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(165) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HWND'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(140) : error C2065: 'WS_CHILD' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(140) : error C2065: 'WS_CLIPCHILDREN' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(140) : error C2065: 'WS_CLIPSIBLINGS' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(140) : error C2065: 'WS_TABSTOP' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(141) : error C2065: 'WS_VISIBLE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(142) : error C2065: 'parent_window' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(142) : error C2065: 'hWndParent' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(143) : error C2065: 'windowRect' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(143) : error C2228: left of '.left' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(144) : error C2065: 'windowRect' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(144) : error C2228: left of '.top' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(145) : error C2065: 'windowRect' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(145) : error C2228: left of '.right' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(145) : error C2228: left of '.left' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(146) : error C2065: 'windowRect' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(146) : error C2228: left of '.bottom' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(146) : error C2228: left of '.top' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(150) : error C2065: 'WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(150) : error C2065: 'WS_CLIPCHILDREN' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(150) : error C2065: 'WS_CLIPSIBLINGS' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(151) : error C2065: 'WS_VISIBLE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(152) : error C2065: 'parent_window' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(152) : error C2065: 'hWndParent' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(153) : error C2065: 'CW_USEDEFAULT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(154) : error C2065: 'CW_USEDEFAULT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(155) : error C2065: 'CW_USEDEFAULT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(156) : error C2065: 'CW_USEDEFAULT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(158) : error C2065: 'windowName' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(158) : error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(158) : error C2228: left of '.length' must have class/struct/union
        type is 'unknown-type'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(158) : error C2660: 'cef_string_utf16_set' : function does not take 3 arguments
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(167) : error C2065: 'parent_window' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(167) : error C2065: 'hWndParent' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_base.h(98) : error C3861: 'InterlockedIncrement': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_base.h(105) : error C3861: 'InterlockedDecrement': identifier not found
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(287) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetWindowHandle'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(287) : error C2433: 'CefBrowserHost::HWND' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(287) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(295) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetOpenerWindowHandle'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(295) : error C2433: 'CefBrowserHost::HWND' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(295) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(468) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MSG'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(474) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MSG'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(287) : error C2253: 'CefBrowserHost::GetWindowHandle' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_browser.h(295) : error C2253: 'CefBrowserHost::GetOpenerWindowHandle' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_keyboard_handler.h(59) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MSG'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_keyboard_handler.h(71) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MSG'
C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/cef_render_handler.h(129) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HCURSOR'
src\gui\HtmlGuiComponent.cpp(179) : error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'clickCount'
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Some errors that jump out at me are:

```
\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows64\include/internal/cef_win.h(59) : error C3861: 'EnterCriticalSection': identifier not found
```

But this *should* be found, as `cef_win.h` clearly includes `<windows.h>` before it tries to call `EnterCriticalSection`.

There are various other errors that seem like they shouldn't be occuring.

I created a simple little sample file, which includes that same CEF3 header files that my project uses, and compiled using SCons, and it compiled just fine.  The sample app is below:

```
/* Sample C/C++, Windows, link to kernel32.dll */
#include <cef_app.h>
#include <cef_client.h>
#include <cef_render_handler.h>


static CRITICAL_SECTION cs; /* This is the critical section object -- once initialized,
                               it cannot be moved in memory */
                            /* If you program in OOP, declare this as a non-static member in your class */ 
void f()
{
    /* Enter the critical section -- other threads are locked out */
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    /* Do some thread-safe processing! */

    /* Leave the critical section -- other threads can now EnterCriticalSection() */
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}

int main()
{
    /* Initialize the critical section before entering multi-threaded context. */
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);

    f(); 

    /* Release system object when all finished -- usually at the end of the cleanup code */
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why I would be getting these errors?

Comment: Try to eliminate errors from the beginning, cause some of them can produce errors later, so as you fix 1st error - you can get different 2nd, 3rd, etc errors, for example what in cef_types_win.h(55)?

Comment: But that's the thing (I think): There IS no syntax error on line 55, or anywhere near there...

Comment: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'instance' usually means that compiler cannot resolve type of variable instance, and supposes it is name of the function

Comment: Right, it can't resolve `HINSTANCE`, which should have been defined in `windows.h`....right?

Comment: looks so, check what headers are included prior it, at least one of them: BaseTsd.h; WinDef.h; WinNT.h, also, do you use any kind of precompiled headers?

Comment: hmm..nope, it just includes `<windows.h>` and another header that was written for the CEF3 library...

Comment: As for precompiled headers, I'm not sure...I don't in my project, but I don't know if CEF3 does...what should I look for?  All I am including (as far as I know) is a bunch of plain looking header .h files..

Comment: try to compile single Animation.cpp file with /showIncludes to check what files are actually included

Comment: Thanks for the help Ilya:) ...looks like nothing is getting included after the `<windows.h>` include bit in `cef_types_win.h`...full output is here: http://pastebin.com/Vi7geU8W

Comment: hard to tell what the problem is, maybe somebody defined _WINDOWS_ or _INC_WINDOWS? I would change windows.h to throw some error in case it defined

Comment: GAH!  Yes, you were right Ilya - `FreeImage.h` was defining `_WINDOWS_` if it wasn't already defined.  I just had to re-order by includes to work around it...Ridiculous how much grief that caused me haha.  Thanks Ilya!  If you want to put your answer below, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per comments: `windows.h` file wasn't included, because other script defined `_WINDOWS_`